# reading variable length string arrays as ints

Tags: c, arrays, string, int, scanf

So I'm trying to read input from file that is formatted like this:

```
0 3 4 1
1 2 4
2
3
4 2
```

The piece of code that I've written here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  if (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL){
     printf("\n%s\n", line);
     int length = strlen(line);
     printf("line = %d\n", length);
     for (int j = 2; j < length; j+=2){
        char a;
        a = line[j];
        int u = a - '0';
        printf("line[%d] = %d\n", j, u);
     }
   }
}
```

is very crude but handles the above single digit type input, however I need it to handle double digit values. I thought about using sscanf() but the line inputs can contain an arbitrary number of values so I don't know how many times to call it. Any assistance here would be great as I'm at a loss... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `strtol`

Here is an example of how to use it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[20]="1 8 0 8 99";  // or your line
    char *pt;

    int numbers[10];  // array to read the numbers
    int index = 0, i; 

    numbers[index] = strtol(str, &pt, 10); // decimal numbers
    index++;

    while(*pt !='\0' )
    {
        numbers[index] = strtol(pt, &pt, 10);
        index++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<index; i++) printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    return 0;

}
```

The output in this example will be :

`1 8 0 8 99`

Now I let you the task of integrating `strtol` in your actual program good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  if (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL){
     printf("\n%s\n", line);
     int length = strlen(line);
     printf("line = %d\n", length);
     int len, u;
     sscanf(line, "%*d%n", &len);
     for (int j=len;sscanf(line + j, "%d%n", &u, &len)==1;j+=len){
        printf("line[%d] = %d\n", j+1, u);//+1 : one space
     }
   }
}
```